# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not working

Tags: iphone, ios

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
}
```

are not working, and i dont hv any idea,why.
When i try debugging, and rotate the device, these method not called.

I just want to detect the orientation
if orientation = landscape
perform action a
else
perform action b

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you set all orientations as supported in your project settings?

Comment: And what's your view hierarchy like? This should be in the top view controller

Comment: got it running, the issue is, i hv define didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation in my both the classes , splashview as well as in mainview.Now its up and running. Thanks for the response Clafou.Regards

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Clafou, how you setup your app can mess with rotation.

Add this and see if it fires:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    BOOL isPortraitOrientation;

    if ((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){

        isPortraitOrientation = YES;

    } else if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){

        isPortraitOrientation = NO;

    }
}
```